# InitializeComponent takes long time in x64

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, 64-bit

I develop an application in C# (winforms). It is quite big and has lots of controls on its form, including user controls. If I run it as Win32 code (under either 32-bit or 64-bit Windows 7) it starts quite fast. However if I compile it as native x64, it takes 15-20 seconds (spent executing InitializeComponent()) before it starts. In both cases, the application runs, so apart from this long delay, I have no problems with the x64 version.

What can cause this and is there anything I can do?

Thanks.

Comment: Try using a profiler to see if there is a specific component causing the slowdown.

Comment: If possible NGEN should make it fast. I also have a long startup delay (4 secs vs 0.5 secs in 32bit mode). Also is there any reason the app needs to run under 64bit?

Comment: It seems related to the JIT struggling with huge method bodies (well, my guess anyways ;p)

Comment: It has to be native 64-bit. I already dropped the x86 version altogether. There is a c++ component that benefits from all the RAM you may have in your PC.
I tried to debug the method and the strange thing is that the 15 second delay happens before InitializeComponent starts. Just pressing F11 on the line that starts it takes 15 seconds. After that, if I just hit F5 to run through the whole method defining and setting up all the controls takes only 2-3 seconds, not longer. Do you think it is JIT and cannot be helped?